# Using INDEX MATCH with NOW to get most recent event from column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet with events/descriptions and the specific time the event begins. I am trying to get the event description for the current time (NOW). I have tried a function =INDEX(K2:K,MATCH(NOW()-TODAY(),L2:L,1)) But it is not working.

The sheet itself has a lot of info in it, but the section where I am trying to figure this out is basically L:Q
I've attached an image, markdown table and sheet link.
Thank you for your time and input!

[events description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StcCT.png)

[google sheet link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pBAZCP1d2JIshQP-UrkNwa9pdgtmVHaONHU3weX1FPo/edit?usp=sharing)

| Return Just Todays Date | Location | Description | Event's Time | How long is event? | **CURRENT EVENT** | How long is event? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12/8/2023 | Jill's office | Outline for Ford presentation | 9:00:AM | 1:15 | #N/A |  |
| 12/8/2023 | Room C | Get notes back to Sam | 10:45:AM | 2:15 |  |  |
| 12/8/2023 | Harrison's Cafe | Review site updates | 1:00:PM | 1:30 |  |  |
| 12/8/2023 | Soulo's Kitchen +Cafe, 635 N Broadway, Los Angeles, CA 90012, USA | Ask about Sara | 6:30:PM | 3:00 |  |  |

Comment: To get most recent event use `SORT()` function as descending order then grab only first one. You can do it by `SORT()` then `INDEX()` or using `QUERY()`.

Comment: your sheet is private by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   LET(event, C2:C,
       event_time, --REGEXREPLACE(D2:D,":([AP])","$1"),
       event_duration, E2:E,
       current_time, NOW() - TODAY(),
       FILTER(event, (current_time >= event_time) *
                     (current_time <= event_time + event_duration))))
```